# How to trim images with Imager

Tags: image, perl

I use the Perl [`Imager`](http://search.cpan.org/~tonyc/Imager-0.94/Imager.pm) library to process images.

I am trying to do something similar to the `trim` operation in ImageMagick or `autocrop` in GIMP: eliminate empty white space at the borders of the image.

Is there such a thing? I've searched the documentation but found nothing.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but ... why don't you use **use Image::Magick; **, and Trim()?

Comment: All that I've written until now is based on Imager and would require a re-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of luck regarding a prewritten `Imager` method to do what you want. But I have looked at what the C API has to offer and I think it should be reasonably simple to write an XS extension to do the job.

My approach would be to pick apart the `ImageMagick` code for the `Trim` function and implement it in terms of the `Imager` API, which defines an `i_gpix` function to determine the colour of individual pixels.

Rather than duplicate the function of the `Imager` `crop` function, I would choose that the XS code returned left, right, top, and bottom margin sizes that could be passed directly to the existing `crop`.

Not what you were hoping for, I know, but well within the bounds of possibility.